# objective c setting an object to a class that is not known

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, uiviewcontroller

I have an array of view controllers (there are more that I have shown):

```
..
settings = [[settingsSettingTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"settingsTab" bundle:nil];
other = [[otherSettingTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"otherTab" bundle:nil];
..

NSArray *views = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:settings,other, nil];
```

I then loop through them and assign some details to them before pushing them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < views.count; i++) {
...
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([[views objectAtIndex:i] class]);
Class myClass = NSClassFromString(className);

myClass *subView = (myClass*)[views objectAtIndex:i];

[self.scrollView addSubview:subView.view];
}
```

How can I assign the right class to the *subView. It worked fine when I had only one type of view in my array and then I just used:

```
settingTab *subView = (settingTab*)[views objectAtIndex:i];
```

But now I need to check and use the right one. I have googled the question, but I'm not sure of how I would describe it? (dynamic typing? Duck typing?) Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is the whole code:

```
NSArray *titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Basics", @"Colours", @"Shapes", @"Settings", @"Other", nil];

basics = [[basicsSettingTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"basicsTab" bundle:nil];
colours = [[colorsSettingTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"colorsTab" bundle:nil];
shapes = [[shapesSettingTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"shapesTab" bundle:nil];
settings = [[settingsSettingTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"settingsTab" bundle:nil];
other = [[otherSettingTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"otherTab" bundle:nil];

NSArray *views = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: basics,colours,shapes,settings,other, nil];

for (int i = 0; i < views.count; i++) {


    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i + 20;
    frame.origin.y = 0;

    CGFloat newWidth = 280;
    CGFloat newHeight = 320;
    CGFloat locx = 0;
    CGFloat locy = 0;

    CGRect panel = CGRectMake(locx, locy, newWidth, newHeight);

    frame.size = panel.size;//self.scrollView.frame.size;
    //subview.view.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([[views objectAtIndex:i] class]);
    Class myClass = NSClassFromString(className);

    myClass *subView = (myClass*)[views objectAtIndex:i];
    [subView.view setFrame:frame];
    subView.tabTitle.text = [titles objectAtIndex:i];

    [subView.view.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
    [subView.view.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

     subView.delegate = self;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:subView.view];
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * views.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
pageControl.numberOfPages = views.count;
```

}

Comment: Why do you need to know class of object in this case? If they are all subclasses of `UIViewController` then `[self.scrollView addSubview:subView.view];` will work quite well

Comment: I have tried that I think. It might be how I am doing things that is confusing. I have added the whole section of code to make more sense.

Comment: Does this even compile?  What Nekto said should be fine.  You *think* you tried it?  What errors did you get?

Comment: When I had the classes of the 'basics, colours...etc' all set as my class settingsTab and the 'myClass *subView = (myClass*)[views objectAtIndex:i];' using settingsTab it did, and ran fine, but now I am trying it dynamically i'm stuck! I get errors on myClass *subView = ... and then ref to subView after that since its not declared! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your edit, we see that you have a property `tabTitle` on each of your custom view controllers. I would recommend that you create a new `UIViewController` subclass that implements `tabTitle`, and use that as the superclass for each of your custom controllers. That way your code only needs to know that they are all a `MyTabViewController` class (for want of a better class name!). So in your for loop:

```
MyTabViewController *subview = (MyTabViewController *)[views objectAtIndex:i];
[subview.view setFrame:frame];
[subview.tabTitle setText:[titles objectAtIndex:i]];

// ...

[self.scrollView addSubview:subView.view];
```

Everything else (`view` property for example) is defined by `UIViewController`, from which all your subclasses are descendants.


**EDIT**

Incidentally, I would be careful about the naming of your objects - your view controllers are not `view`s. In particular, this might cause confusion where you have `subview.view`. Perhaps more appropriate would be `subviewController.view`, or even just `controller.view`?

Comment: I have tried your way with the parent class and it works brilliantly. Thanks. I will now do some renaming :D

Answer (score 1):

The properties you are setting are common to all through since they all inherit from UIViewController.

replace:

```
myClass *subView = (myClass*)[views objectAtIndex:i];
```

with:

```
UIViewController *subViewController = (UIViewController *)[views objectAtIndex:i];
```

Also, do be careful about using the terms "view" and viewController" interchangably.  They are not the same thing and can get very confusing/complex when you name things like they are.

Comment: That works great, assuming I remove my custom stuff. How can I get access to my custom stuff? For now I will do custom stuff elsewhere :)

Comment: If the custom properties are consistent across all of the view controllers you could make a subclass of UIViewController that is then the super class of all your other classes.  Then you still have one consistent class to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

If all of them are subclasses of UIViewController, then just use it:

```
****
frame.size = panel.size;//self.scrollView.frame.size;
//subview.view.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];

UIViewController* subView = (UIViewController*)[views objectAtIndex:i];

[subView.view setFrame:frame];
****
```

If you are not doing anything special to every view controller, then you just don't need to know exact class of it as long as it is subclass of some known class...

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I do have special stuff. I'll have to come up with a work around, but your code works ok on the generic stuff. Thanks

Comment: In case you do need some speciality, you can check things on runtime with [someObject isKindOfClass:[someClass class]] casting it to that special one if answer positive and doing any of your intended work.